# Why the drupal updated article is visible only for logged in users?

Tags: caching, drupal-7

In my website I am able to see the updated article once logged in but when I logout and go to the same page the article is not the updated one. Is this due to the cache? 
I have cleared the cache but its still the same...

Am in Drupal 7 
Any help :)

Answer (score 1):

Drupal caches pages for anonymous users. Have you tried disabling 'cache pages for anonymous users' to see if that makes a difference?

(screenshot at http://drupal.org/node/797346)

Comment: Yea that worked - But i need to cache pages for better performance - but the solution worked! thanks! :)

Comment: It *should* update the cache for anonymous users at some point, so I don't think you've got a problem ;)